Ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
What's the issue
I have a python script which will make a POST call to Jenkins and Jira to get certain information.
In the Jenkins pipeline, it is configured that a kubernates pod will be created to ssh to a certain linux machine and run this python script.
Originally, a local cert is configured to make a call to Jenkins and Jira.
Started few days ago, for the original script with local cert triggered from Jenkins pipeline, I start to get the error 503 service temporarily unavailable when calling the Jenkins and Jira.
(I have confirmed this error is not related to Jenkins & Jira, as there's no such error calling from another client)
To debug it, I have removed the local cert, and trigger the script directly from the linux machine, there is no error at all, and I managed to retrieve the information from Jira and Jenkins.
Then I run the script on Jenkins with local cert removed, there's error
Ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate from request(“get”, url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/bin/miniconda3-24.1.2-0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket ssl_sock =
_sl_wrap_socket_implsock, context, ts_in_tls, server_hostname)
File "/home/user/bin/miniconda3-24.1.2-0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_py", line 514, in _ssl_ wrap_socket_impl return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
ЛАААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААЛЛАААААЛЛАЛ
File "/home/user/bin/miniconda3-24.1.2-0/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket return self.ss|socket_class._create(
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
File "/home/user/bin/miniconda3-24.1.2-0/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1046, in _create self.do _handshake()
File "/home/user/bin/miniconda3-24.1.2-0/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1321, in do_handshake self._sslobj.do_handshake()
Ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (ssl.c: 1000)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

To summarise the issue



Script Version
From Kube pod ssh to Linux machine to run the script
ssh directly to Linux machine to run the script




No local cert
Ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
No error, managed to retrieve information


With local cert
503 service temporarily unavailable
Never tried



What I want to achieve

I want there to be no error when pipeline creates a Kube pod that ssh to Linux machine to run the script

What I have checked

I tried to query the certificate file for when the TLS/SSL certifation will expire, and confirmed the cert is not expired yet.

What I don't understand & The way to fix and debug it

why when ssh from kubernates pod to linux machine with user A, I will need a cert to call Jenkins and Jira. But why when I ssh directly to linux machine with user A, I don't need a cert to call Jenkins and Jira?
Is it true that there is some issue with the local cert, so I will need to fix the cert?
As the certificate is not expired yet, maybe there is some other thing I need to check?

Can you please advise what might be the issue / how should I debug it?
Thank you very much in advance.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  In the script, where does the TLS certificate come from?  The most likely things to be different between the two ssh paths are probably environment variables; have you debugged os.environ in the script?  Can you ssh directly from the Jenkins runner without involving the hop via a Kubernetes Pod?
